# Most efficient way to split a pandas dataframe column into several columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe column ('x') that contains lists as values.

```
import pandas as pd
jk = pd.DataFrame()
jk['x'] = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 2], [27, 1, 3]]
```

I used the code below to split the values into columns like this. However, my actual data set is very large. I have about 80, 000 rows and 16 values inside every list. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
jk1 = pd.DataFrame(jk.x.values.tolist(), columns=['a','b','c'])
```

[image]

Comment: Working with lists in pandas is always slow. Why can't you change where data frame is created with lists in the first place. Here change where `jk` is created so that it is not column of lists.

Answer (score 0):

## No, there isn't a more efficient way

You should avoid creating a series of lists in the first place. As soon as you do this, you are left with an `object` dtype series with a nested layer of pointers. One layer pointing to each list, and another layer pointing to individual elements within each list. This prohibits vectorised operations.

Comment: @jezrael, Maybe you've misread the question (or I have).. The starting point is a **series of lists**. To expand this into a regular dataframe isn't a vectorisable process. Because you are starting with pointers pointing to containers of more pointers. *After the conversion*, sure, you can take advantage of vectorisation.

Comment: @jezrael, Feel free to add an answer. And if you're right, I'll delete this one :).

Comment: @jezrael, Oh yes, that's what OP has though. He's asking for a **more efficient** solution than `jk.x.values.tolist()`. I can't see any.